# Visual Studio 2010 hardcoding unwanted values in Designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have a user control on a form in Visual Studio, which is a custom date entry control (called for the purposes of discussion `CustomDate`). This control contains a property called `CompareDate` which is of type `DateTime`. This gets/sets a value to a private variable called `compareDate`. (Not a control or anything just a variable used for internal logic)

I place this control on a form `CustomerForm` and call it `uctCustomDate`.

For some reason any change ever made to `CustomerForm` causes a line to be automatically inserted into `CustomerForm.Designer.cs` hard-coding the value of `uctCustomDate.CompareDate` to today's date!

Is there a way to avoid this? I can just delete the line and build the application but it means I have to remember to do this every time I make a change to this form. Anything I should look out for (e.g. that another developer might have put in)?

Here's some code if it helps...

in `CompareDate.cs`

```
private DateTime compareDate = DateTime.Today;   // BTW it happens whether or not I initialise to DateTime.Today

.
.
.

public DateTime CompareDate 
{
    get { return compareDate; }
    set { compareDate = value; }
}
```

And the code automatically inserted to `CustomerForm.Designer.cs` whenever I make a change on the `CustomerForm` form design

```
// 
// uctCustomDate
// 
this.uctCustomDate.CompareDate = new System.DateTime(2015, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `BrowsableAttribute` on `CompareDate` property, it will not be displayed in `Properties` window in form designer

if you use `DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute` with visibility = `Hidden` on `CompareDate`, property will not be serialized in `CustomerForm.Designer.cs`

[[DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

existing lines `this.uctCustomDate.CompareDate = ...` will not be removed automatically from Designers files

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public DateTime CompareDate 
{
    get { return compareDate; }
    set { compareDate = value; }
}
```

Comment: This does remove it from the Properties window but it doesn't stop the initialisation if I make a change to the form.

Comment: @colmde, you are right: Browsable(false) doesn't solve it. i updated my answer now

Comment: Ah, this really helped me out. On an expanded `NumericUpDown` control it kept resetting the initially shown value to the minimum due to one of the other properties it initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making compareDate a nullable Datetime ? This way the designer should not initialize it by himself.

```
DateTime? compareDate;


public DateTime? CompareDate 
{
    get { return compareDate; }
    set { compareDate = value; }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't stop the designer from inserting the code if I make a change to the form